# How to receive local notification when app is closed in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, notifications, localnotification

I use [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package. My app works correctly and sends notification on time when it's open. But if it be closed, no notification sends until it becomes open. How to solve this problem?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
     flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
     to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="test5"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
<receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
<receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
             until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
             there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
             defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
            android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Initializing:

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'); 
    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
  }
```

Comment: By looking at the manifest file it looks right. May I ask you how are you initializing it on your code?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: Looks ok. Does that happen will multiple android versions/devices? I’ve been using local notifications on both iOS and android without any issue.

Comment: @MiguelRuivo I tested it with version 9 and didn't work correctly. But now I'm testing it with an android version 5 and it works.

Comment: @MiguelRuivo In build.gradle, targetSdkVersion is 27. Maybe I should change it to 28.

Comment: Does the docs say anything about minimum/target versions? I believe it will work only on 17 and above.

Comment: any one find any solution ? i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

Note sure what version of the plugin you're running but it requires that you've migrated your app to AndroidX, which in turn requires targeting 28 e.g. see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#not-recommended-manually-migrate-your-app